# Running Wand on lambda return ImageMagick in the system is likely to be impossible to load liblqr

Tags: aws-lambda, imagemagick, serverless-framework, wand

Trying to  run wand library  to resize image  image  using liquid resize in serverless  framework when  invoke the  function locally it works  fine. but running  on  Lambda  results in  the following error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "delegate library support not built-in `' (LQR) @ error/resize.c/LiquidRescaleImage/1884\n\nImageMagick in the system is likely to be impossible to load liblqr.  You might not install liblqr, or ImageMagick may not compiled with liblqr.",
    "errorType": "MissingDelegateError",
    "stackTrace": [
        [
            "/var/task/handler.py",
            123,
            "imageprocess",
            "liquid.liquid_rescale(width, height)"
        ],
        [
            "/var/task/wand/image.py",
            865,
            "wrapped",
            "result = function(self, *args, **kwargs)"
        ],
        [
            "/var/task/wand/image.py",
            3322,
            "liquid_rescale",
            "str(e) + '\\n\\nImageMagick in the system is likely to be '"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Lambda is likely using a different version of ImageMagick and delegates and the lambda version likely does not have liblqr installed as a delegate. Check the versions and what delegates show when you do `convert -version` on both.

Comment: could you  tell me how to check version in  lambda

Comment: Sorry, I do not know or use Lambda. One other issue is to be sure you have set environment variable to point to imagemagick in Lambda. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment. Wish I could help more. Perhaps a Google search might uncover something that will help.

Comment: I do not know if these will be helpful, but see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174072 and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=167040 and perhaps https://www.mschweighauser.com/create-a-thumbnail-api-service/

Comment: To get the ImageMagick version from Wand, see wand.version.MAGICK_VERSION at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.1/wand/version.html#wand.version.VERSION_INFO

Comment: See also wand.version.formats and wand.version.configure_options  and wand.version.MAGICK_VERSION_FEATURES

Comment: AWS's lambda does not offer `liblqr` delegate library, so `Image.liquid_rescale` is not available for a server-less application.